# Android getting real size vs display metrics width and height pixels

Tags: android, size, screen

Ok so when I use metrics.heightpixels on android nexus 5(and Im using genymotion emulator) it gives me like 1776 or something. And the reason for this is because of the back and home buttons and the bottom. Problem is I want to know for game development should I be getting the real size or the size AVAILIBLE(meaning minus the buttons)? I mean if the space there isnt available then there's no point in calculations based on it right?

Comment: Do you want things in your game to be under the buttons?

Comment: There are ways to get rid of those buttons.  So do you want them around when the game is in use or not?

Comment: @Saturisk Not unreasonable if he's using the immersion APIs.

Comment: @Saturisk I don't which is why I should use display metrics right?